# SQL combining 3 tables and get just the row with the latest date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables `user`, `session` and `log`. The user table stores all user relevant information while the session just connects the user with the log. And i want to get a list of all users with the latest log entry. The table design looks like this:

```
user (id, name, ...)
session (id, user_id)
log (id, session_id, time, type, ...)
```

My current query looks like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM   USER AS u 
       INNER JOIN session AS s 
               ON u.id = s.user_id 
       INNER JOIN log AS l 
               ON l.session_id = s.id 
ORDER  BY l.time DESC
```

But it's not hard to imagine that this just returns the data of all 3 tables sorted by date. How do i achieve a result that i just get every user just once with the data from the latest log entry ordered by the time of log (desc)?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DISTINCT ON](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-select-distinct/) in conjunction with `ORDER BY` to get the latest row per user by log date. This will allow you to select the additional fields you need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (u.id) 
    u.id,
    u.Name,
    l.type,
    l.time
FROM user AS u 
    INNER JOIN session AS s ON u.id = s.user_id
    INNER JOIN log AS l ON l.session_id = s.id
ORDER BY u.id, l.time DESC;
```

*N.B. I don't know exactly what columns you need, but I have added a couple in to demonstrate as I don't like to advocate the use of `SELECT *`*

---

For completeness there are a couple of other ways to achieve this, the first is to select the max in a subquery and join back to the outer query on both user_id and time:

```
SELECT  u.id,
        u.Name,
        l.type,
        l.time
FROM    user AS u 
        INNER JOIN session AS s 
            ON u.id = s.user_id
        INNER JOIN log AS l 
            ON l.session_id = s.id
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  s.user_id, MAX(l.time) AS time
            FROM    session AS s
                    INNER JOIN log AS l
                        ON l.session_id = s.id
            GROUP BY s.user_id
        ) AS MaxLog
            ON MaxLog.user_id = u.id
            AND MaxLog.time = l.time
ORDER BY l.time DESC;
```

Or you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT  id, Name, type, time
FROM    (   SELECT  u.id,
                    u.Name,
                    l.type,
                    l.time,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY u.id ORDER BY l.time DESC) AS RowNumber
            FROM    user AS u 
                    INNER JOIN session AS s 
                        ON u.id = s.user_id
                    INNER JOIN log AS l 
                        ON l.session_id = s.id
        ) u
WHERE   RowNumber = 1;
```

Comment: The edited version of your post was exactly what i was looking for. Thank you so much! 
I'm currently using your `ROW_NUMBER()` approach, what would you personally recommend to use?

Comment: I'd say test them all, check the execution plans and see which one works best for you. I'd guess at either `DISTINCT ON` or `ROW_NUMBER`, they will have the least reads, but to be honest I have very little practical experience with Postgresql, so I am not 100% sure which of these two performs better.

Comment: I personally prefer ROW_NUMBER because it is more adaptable (i.e. if you decide you want the top 2 per user you only need to change `WHERE RowNumber = 1` to `WHERE RowNumber <= 2`), and I find it easy to understand what the query is doing, but this is entirely subjective, and if there is a performance difference that would influence my decision more than readability or adaptability.

Answer (score 1):

I've assumed some schema (`user.user_name`?), but you can do this by grouping and an aggregate like `Max`:

```
SELECT u.user_id, 
        u.user_name, 
       Max(l.time) AS LastLogTime 
FROM   USER AS u 
       LEFT JOIN session AS s 
              ON u.id = s.user_id 
       INNER JOIN log AS l 
               ON l.session_id = s.id 
GROUP  BY u.user_id, 
          u.user_name;
```

You won't be able to `select *` as we need to use `GROUP BY`
Similarly, `ORDER BY l.time` isn't applicable any more - you could still order by e.g. `user_name`
I've also `LEFT JOINED` - this way, if the user has no sessions, it will still return a record for the user, possibly with a `LastLogTime` of NULL.

Comment: If the OP wants to have the list ordered by the latest log time, it is still possible to `order by 3`

Comment: Thanks for your insanely fast response!
Your assumption was right, and it works fine if I just want to get the user data with latest date. But when I try to get additional data from log like `type` i need to add it to the group statement what makes the whole thing useless again :(

Comment: By adding additional columns to the `SELECT`, you are effectively creating new categories / buckets in which to classify calculated aggregated data like `LastLogTime` against. So either add the additional SELECT columns to the `GROUP BY`, or apply other aggregate functions to them (e.g. `SELECT ... , MIN(type)` in which case you won't need to GROUP BY, but you will get a fairly meaningless `type`.?